# 'main class not found in class' with Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, jvm

i generated the project in intellij, its meant to use jvm and kotlin, i have a src directory, i created a kotlin class called Bot, currently it looks like this:

```
class Bot{
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            println("hello")
        }
    }
}
```

but ive also tried:

```
class Bot{
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        println("hello")
    }
}
```

or just :

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("hello")
}
```

i pointed out this class in configuration by hand, but each time i try to run my project i get `Function main not found in class Bot`, while its clearly there... Can you guys give me an example of an example class that will let me run my app?[image]

Comment: Your third option is the way to do it. The main function should not be inside a class. Click the little green play button next to it to run it.

Comment: then it tells me it cannot find the Bot class

Comment: Are you sure you aren't clicking the play button at the top right toolbar (with your incorrectly set up run configuration) rather than the play button next to your main function in the gutter by the line numbers?

Comment: im blind, i cant see it, is it visible on the screen i posted?

Comment: it began working when i change the name of the class to Main, with first example

Comment: It's not on your screen because you don't have a valid main function in that screen shot. If you have a valid main function (or main method in Java), IntelliJ shows it next to the line number.

Answer (score -2):

Change you class for an object and add platformStatic to your main method

```
object Main {
  platformStatic fun main(args: Array<String>){
    println("hello")
  }
}
```

or put your main function outside the class

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    println("hello")
}
```

Comment: platformStatic does not work.
In current Kotlin platformStatic has changed to an annotation @JvmStatic